# Add new port in running docker compose

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to add a SSL certificate to a wordpress container but the default compose configuration only redirects port 80.

How can I add a new port in the running container? I tried to modify the docker-compose.yml file and restart the container but this doesn't solve the problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

You should re-create container, when listening new port, like this

```
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate {CONTAINER}
```

Answer (score 1):

Expose ports.

Either specify both ports (HOST:CONTAINER), or just the container port (an ephemeral host port is chosen).

Note: When mapping ports in the HOST:CONTAINER format, you may experience erroneous results when using a container port lower than 60, because YAML parses numbers in the format xx:yy as a base-60 value. For this reason, we recommend alway**s explicitly specifying your port mappings as strings.**

ports:
 - "3000"
 - "3000-3005"
 - "8000:8000"
 - "9090-9091:8080-8081"
 - "49100:22"
 - "127.0.0.1:8001:8001"
 - "127.0.0.1:5000-5010:5000-5010"
 - "6060:6060/udp"
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#pid

Answer (score 1):

After you add the new port to the docker-compose file, what I did that works is:

1. Stop the container

   docker-compose stop <service name>
2. Run the docker-compose up command (NOTE:  docker-compose start  did not work)

   docker-compose up -d

According to the documentation the 'docker-compose' command:

> Builds, (re)creates, starts, and attaches to containers for a service
> ... Unless they are already running

That started up the stopped service, WITH the exposed ports I had configured.

Comment: You shouldn't need to manually `docker-compose stop` the existing container; Compose knows that it needs to delete and recreate it to add the port and `docker-compose up` will do that on its own (as the other answers to this question have).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like in this example:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports

Should work like this:

```
my-services:
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
```

Answer (score -1):

you just add the new port in the port section of the `docker-compose.yml` and then you must do

```
docker-compose up -d
```

because it will read the .yml file again and recreate the container. If you do just restart it will not read the new config from the .yml and just restart the same container.